# asp.net mvc application need access to users google drive account from "service"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

Im writing a web-app that gives our customers the possibility to SYNC their files on their personal Google Drive onto OUR bushiness application. (only limited file types).

So - what works so far:

- Users signup to the app, (using OAuth2 and saves a refreshtoken in my end) the user/and my app, have now access to files on their Drive, and can **manually** invoke file transfers.

Working fine.

- Users can afterwards login again and repeat this without having to authenticate the app again. Fine.
- In parallel, I need some kind "service" that loops thru our app's user-base and AUTOMATICALLY syncs files in a designated folder - say every 10 mins.

Now im running into problems because of OAuth2 model, needs to redirect to authenticate every user. But I cannot make multiple redirects out of a single request to, say "/SyncAllUsers".
Also, when testing with one user only, the user still have to be logged in into the browser session, or else google will redirect to the service-login page.

(We use a chron-job to invoke these methods at a specified interval - and it is working well with dropbox-accounts, and these users also use OAuth)

---

So basically 2 questions:

- How can I access my users Drive accounts, with my already authorized app, without having users to "be logged in"
- And how should I handle the sync-service to run without having to redirect at every user.

I have spent days searching for answers on https://developers.google.com/drive/ and in here.
I have impl. the OAuth code from here https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials#retrieve_oauth_20_credentials
and I modified it so it is using my own user-database.

For your infomation im using the Client ID for web applications, in Google APIs Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the refresh token, you can use it to perform synchronization without user intervention. This is the nature of `offline` access and the whole purpose of a refresh token.

(Sorry if this doesn't answer your question, I am not exactly sure what you are asking, so please explain more and I will try to give you a different/better answer.)

Comment: Hi Ali. Thx for the answer - I found it myself a few weeks, and forgot to post the solution in here. But this `offline` parameter in the url  did the trick - just too bad that the examples on developer site doesn't make this as clear.
Enjoying your dev-videos by the way ;)